# Save button on product page does not work in Magento 2.1.6

Tags: magento2.1.6

New products and even existing products that are opened to be modified could not be saved in Magento 2.1.6. There is not JS error thrown, the Save button just does nothing. No request goes out on the network either.

Re-indexed, re-cached, re-deployed contents, without errors. The only thing I've done is that I've upgraded from Magento 2.1.2 to 2.1.6.

What could be the problem? Ideas to figure it out?

Comment: Which js error ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that some hidden fields, that are part of the product form, were not opened. There is an "Advanced price" section under the price input field, in which there are additional input fields present. One of them was mandatory. **Unfortunately, Magento says nothing about why the click on the "Save" button has been discarded.**

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Magento 2.1.6 and I've not personally experienced this issue.

In my opinion, one option to check is the system Locale. Make sure that you static content is deployed for all/related locale otherwise you'd get errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that some hidden fields, that are part of the product form, were not opened. There is an **"Advanced price"** section under the **Cost input field**, in which there are additional input fields present. One of them was mandatory. Unfortunately, Magento says nothing about why the click on the "Save" button has been discarded.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue also. I fixed it by find out the cause why the button doesn't work.
The cause is data of product invalid. In my case it's max_sale_qty = 0 but it must be positive value.

The detail is here, I wrote a post here for detail solution.

https://mrvts.wordpress.com/2020/02/05/save-button-on-product-page-does-not-work-in-magento-2-admin/